# What is the idiomatic approach for shared immutable references in tide and Tokio?

Tags: rust, rust-tokio

I am working on a RPC client using a tide server with state. I put another client into that state so my endpoints can use it:

```rust
let client = MintClient::new(cfg, Arc::new(db), Default::default());
let state = State {
    mint_client: Arc::new(client),
};
let mut app = tide::with_state(state);
```

The endpoints are:

```rust
app.at("/info")
    .post(|req: tide::Request<State>| async move {
        let State { ref mint_client } = req.state();
        Body::from_json(&InfoResponse::new(mint_client.coins()))
    });
```

I copied the `Arc` from existing code, but I don't know how it works and someone told me its unnecessary in my situation.

If I don't use a `State`, I get the error "this closure implements `FnOnce`, not `Fn`". If I remove the `move` so it borrows the client, I get "may outlive borrowed value `client`" on the `req` parameter.

I don't know how to approach this. Should I use functions as the endpoints instead of closures and pass a immutable reference to them and then use generic lifetime? Is it possible to use generic lifetimes on closures too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`with_state` requires the state to implement `Clone + Send + Sync + 'static` (see https://docs.rs/tide/0.16.0/tide/fn.with_state.html ).

If you want to share MintClient, not clone it, you'll need some type of a reference. Since thread-safety is required (Send + Sync), you can't use ordinary references (with lifetimes) or Rc, it has to be Arc.

> but I don't know how it works and someone told me its unnecessary in my situation.

Arc owns the object, and can provide a usual immutable reference to you on demand. It implements Clone, so it is possible to create multiple copies of it (that's useful for sharing). It implements Send + Sync, so it is possible to pass safely between threads without data races (Tokio is multi-threaded).

The owned object is kept alive until the last Arc clone drops. In your case it is tied to the `app` lifetime, so it probably never drops the MintClient while the server is running.

Read more here:
https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/struct.Arc.html